# checking validation of form - pass validation if one is filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

[image: contact details]
At moment - this is section is incomplete as the user doesn't fill in the home no. and office/other contact no.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have this section checked as completed if the user filled in either home no. or office/other contact no. so basically once they filled one of them the error message on both will disappear
Any help would be appreciated.

```
        <div class="signup-card-section">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header boldtext">Tell us 
                     about your contact details <div class="section-complete"><i class="icon-tick"></i> Completed</div></h2>                            

                    <div class="column-control no-padding twelve colgrid">
                      <fieldset>
                        <p><i>Please provide at least 2 contact numbers</i></p>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="four columns">
                            <label for="mobile">Mobile No.<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                            <div class="columns" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 7px;">+</div>
                            <div class="two columns">
                              <input id="mobileprefix" name="mobileprefix" type="text" value="65" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nine columns">
                              <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="input numeric-only readonly" value="0121234567" maxlength="14" readonly>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="four columns">
                            <label for="mobile">Home No.</label>
                            <div class="columns" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 7px;">+</div>
                            <div class="two columns">
                              <input id="homeprefix" name="homeprefix" type="text" value="65" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nine columns">
                              <input id="homeno" name="homeno" type="text" class="input numeric-only phone-group" placeholder="eg: 0121234567" maxlength="14">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="four columns">
                            <label for="mobile">Office/Other Contact No.</label>
                            <div class="columns" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 7px;">+</div>
                            <div class="two columns">
                              <input id="otherprefix" name="homeprefix" type="text" value="65" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nine columns">
                              <input id="otherno" name="otherno" type="text" class="input numeric-only phone-group" placeholder="eg: 0121234567" maxlength="14">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="four columns">
                            <label for="email">Email address <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="test@mail.com" class="input readonly" readonly>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                      </fieldset>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

in my JS file I have set a validation rule:

```
 $(".signup-card").validate({
  ignore:"",
  rules: {
    homeno: {
      required: true
    },
    otherno: {
      required: true
    }
  },
    messages: {
      homeno: {
            required: "Required field"
           },

       otherno: {
            required: "Required field"
           },
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use require_from_group method Source: https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/

Add a class `phone-group` to your HTML input and update your rule as mentioned below.

```
 $(".signup-card").validate({
      ignore:"",
      rules: {
        homeno: {
          require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
        },
        otherno: {
          require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
        }
      },
        messages: {
          homeno: {
                required: "Required field"
               },

           otherno: {
                required: "Required field"
               },
          }
        });
```

Comment: @rory-h Please create a fiddle so it's easier for us to debug.

Comment: I did exactly what you did and got an error. Do I need an additional js or something?